# NativeLibrary permission in applet html

Tags: java, jna, japplet, libvlc, vlcj

applet exception for reading data in NativeLibrary

applet exception

```
java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at com.sun.jna.NativeLibrary.<clinit>(NativeLibrary.java:79)
    at Applet$1.run(Applet.java:39)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at Applet.init(Applet.java:36)
    at com.sun.deploy.uitoolkit.impl.awt.AWTAppletAdapter.init(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2Manager$AppletExecutionRunnable.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.security.AccessControlException: access denied ("java.util.PropertyPermission" "jna.tmpdir" "read")
    at java.security.AccessControlContext.checkPermission(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.checkPermission(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.SecurityManager.checkPermission(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin2.applet.AWTAppletSecurityManager.checkPermission(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.SecurityManager.checkPropertyAccess(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.System.getProperty(Unknown Source)`enter code here`
    at com.sun.jna.Native.getTempDir(Native.java:995)
    at com.sun.jna.Native.removeTemporaryFiles(Native.java:1018)
    at com.sun.jna.Native.loadNativeLibrary(Nativeenter code here.java:677)
    at com.sun.jna.Native.<clinit>(Native.java:129)
    ... 7 more
```

java class code

```
NativeLibrary.addSearchPath(  RuntimeUtil.getLibVlcLibraryName(), "../lib/vlc-files");
```

not exception in eclipse , accurately  execute 
and also grant privileges in file
java.policy.applet

```
grant {
  permission java.security.AllPermission;
  permission java.util.PropertyPermission "jna.tmpdir", "read";
};
```

Comment: Did you sign your applet jar file, and those of vlcj/jna?

Comment: yes i sign the all jar file by jarsigner but problem is not loadding libvlc.dll and libvlccore.dll from vlc-files directory

Comment: Are you sure you signed the jna and platform jars? This error suggests otherwise: "access denied ("java.util.PropertyPermission" "jna.tmpdir" "read")"

Comment: show message after signing jar show message in console "  jar signed.
Warning:
No -tsa or -tsacert is provided and this jar is not timestamped. Without a times
tamp, users may not be able to validate this jar after the signer certificate's
expiration date (4751-12-22) or after any future revocation date."

Comment: The original error definitely points to a failure to sign the jar files. Did you open up the supposedly signed JNA and Platform jar files to check that the digital signatures were in fact present?

Comment: It would probably be easier to deploy this using [Java Web Start](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/java-web-start/info).  Put the natives in the root of a Jar(s one for each platform) then add the Jars in an appropriate `resources` section in the JNLP.  They will be downloaded automatically and added to the run-time native path of the app.